# Check the gridview column check box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an app in C# in which I am using the datagridview and gridview first column contains the checkboxes and I want to chech the checkbox is true or not but it is giving me the exception of 'Object referernce is not set to an instance of an object'. The code is following

```
  private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StudentDAL s = new StudentDAL();

            try 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
                {

                    if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0]) && (bool)this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == true)
                    {

                        s.delete(Convert.ToInt32(this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value));
                        i--;

                    }

                }
                this.dataGridView1.DataSource = s.getAll();

            }
            catch (Exception nn)
            {


            }


        }
```

Please help me.

Comment: you should get the checkbox control first by `FindControl()` method then check if it checked or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to find your CheckBox control, then you can check it is checked or not like this :

```
    Int32 i;
    CheckBox k;

    for (i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            k = ((CheckBox)(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chk")));
            if (k.Checked == true)
            {
                //your code here
            }
            else
            {
                //your code here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference an object that has not been initialized (I believe in this instance Row[i]).

Try putting a breakpoint inside the for loop and step through (F10) and check what position i is at when it throws the exception.

Comment: On the first time it checks the condition it throws an exception

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Add more validations

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (rw.Cells.Count > 2 && 
        rw.Cells[0].Value != DBNull.Value && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rw.Cells[0].Value.ToString()) &&
        ((bool)rw.Cells[0].Value) &&
            rw.Cells[1].Value != DBNull.Value && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rw.Cells[1].Value.ToString()))
    {
            s.delete(Convert.ToInt32(rw.Cells[1].Value));

    }
}
```